# Passing Android webview JS interface method as callback function

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have the following android code:

```
private class MyJavaInterface {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void call(String number) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

...

mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaInterface(), "MyInterface");
```

This JS code works correctly:

```
MyInterface.call(number);
```

And this does not:

```
var call = MyInterface.call;
call(number);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to create a constructor for MyJavaInterface

Comment: @Sanil nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

> This JS code works correctly:
>
> MyInterface.call(number);

Yes, this will work fine because Android will automatically find the class and the only public methods that are annotated.

For your case

```
MyInterface.call(number) -> new MyJavaInterface().call(number)
```

But the Second one will not work,

```
MyInterface.call -> new MyJavaInterface().call - there is no public variable in your class and also there is no support for variable in addJavascriptInterface
```

Note : [Refer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

> For applications targeted to API level **JELLY_BEAN_MR1** and above, only
>   public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be
>   accessed from JavaScript. For applications targeted to API level
>   **JELLY_BEAN or below**, all public methods (including the inherited ones)
>   can be accessed